# HTTP Python server: javascript no longer works

Tags: javascript, python

I have some JavaScript code that I use to retrieve data from a json file and populate a dropdown list.

- Everything was working fine.
- I added some code and it went into an infinite loop.
- I deleted this code but since then it no longer works on the HTTP server I setup using Python.
- HOWEVER it works perfectly fine when I load it on a network server.
- I deleted Python, reinstalled and still not working.

Logically it can't be the code because it works on the network server... I am totally lost.  Any and all help much appreciated.  I am getting now where fast.  (I can't work from the network server so need this working locally.)

Below is the javascript

```
//this will hold the data from JSON
var teamSkillsData


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //retrieve data from the external json file
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    teamSkillsData = response.teamSkills;
    var select = document.getElementById("teamList"); 
      alert("nn");
    //populate the teamList drop down menu
    for(var i = 0; i < teamSkillsData.length; i++) {
        //assign the team names
        var opt = teamSkillsData[i].team;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = i;
        select.appendChild(el);
        }​
    // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

}
};
xhttp.open("GET", 'Data.json', true);
xhttp.send(); 

 function teamChanged(teamSelected)
        {

            var skills = teamSkillsData[teamSelected].skillset;
            for(var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
                skillsRequired = skills[i];
                alert(skillsRequired);
            }​


        }
```

Comment: Are there errors in the javascript console in the browser?

Comment: Python has nothing to do with javascript. You're probably looking at the wrong code... Try creating a [mcve]

Comment: @Joe Console says "GET /tt.html HTTP/1.1" 200 - (next line same for Data.json)

Comment: `I deleted this code but since then it no longer works`  It might be time to start learning about version control.  You might've deleted more than you thought and broke it.  You don't necessarily need to learn Git (though it could help), but you should be backing up versions as you go somehow.

Comment: @DaveS I normally do but this one slipped past me :(  It's still not logical to me that the exact same files work perfectly on my network server.

Comment: Couldn't get it working so found an older version and updated it.... Really not sure what happened to the file.  Worked find on network but not the Python http server.  Appreciate everyones input :)